# Writing documentation for our JavaScript libraries API

Tags: javascript, api, documentation, documentation-generation

I need to write a documentation for our JavaScript libraries API and publish them as HTML (like the jQuery API site and similar).
I think there are two ways to tackle this task.

1. Write comments in the JavaScript and find a way to parse it (like [JsDoc Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) or [jGrouseDoc](http://jgrouse.com/))
2. Write it manually (in a wiki?)

I'm looking for good tools to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can put Javadoc comments in Javascript code. Use Javadoc.exe in the JDK installation to generate the HTML documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Would love something better :(

Comment: @ravidor what did you use then finally?

Answer (score 0):

[Verb](http://verbiage.io/) seems promising. I'm following it.